# python imp.load_source with dependencies

Tags: python, openshift, python-import

My app has the following layout:

```
/wsgi/myapp/__init__.py
/wsgi/application
/app.py
```

File **_*init*_**.py:

```
from flask import Flask #python flask framework!
def create_app(app_name=None):
    app_name = app_name or __name__
    app = Flask(app_name)
    return app
```

File application (without .py extension!):

```
from myapp import create_app
application = create_app('myapp')

@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return 'My OpenShift Flask app'
```

File app.py has the following line which causes error:

```
import imp
app = imp.load_source('application', 'wsgi/application')
```

The error is "No module named myapp". What else I need to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the import path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('wsgi')
import imp
app = imp.load_source('application', 'wsgi/application')
```

Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'application.py')
application = wsgi.application
```

this should work in python 3